# TypeScript: Possible to apply Pick on a custom type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a custom type like

```
type Fruit = 'apple' | 'orange' | 'banana' | 'grapefruit';
```

From `Fruit`, is it possible to derive yet another custom type like `CitrusFruit` that only contains orange and grapefruit?

This doesn't appear to work:

```
type CitrusFruit = Pick<Fruit, 'orange' | 'grapefruit'>
```

Comment: Why not do it the other way around, so `type Fruit = CitrusFruit | 'apple' | 'banana';`? You could use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), but it seems pointless.

Comment: Pick picks keys from objects, and your type isn't an object. But I would go the other way around, like `type CitrusFruit = 'orange' | 'grapefruit'` and `type Fruit = CitrusFruit | 'apple' | 'banana'`

Comment: Your example that doesn't work can be written even shorter as `type CitrusFruit = 'orange' | 'grapefruit';` Can you share a more realistic example of why you would want to do this with a utility type instead of not, because your way is more verbose than the standard way.

Comment: Extract should possibly work instead of Pick

Comment: Yes, `Extract` and not `Pick`, but it's a weird thing to do, since you need to write out `'orange' | 'grapefruit'` anyway, which is the full type you want to create, so `type CitrusFruit = Extract<Fruit, 'orange' | 'grapefruit'>` is just a longer way of writing `type CitrusFruit = 'orange' | 'grapefruit'`.  Why not write it the shorter way to start with?  What's the actual use case you're trying to satisfy here?